# Simple countdown programs to print "3, 2, 1, Action!" using while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparative-review

My program is a simple while loop making a countdown starting from 3 and shouts "Action!" upon reaching zero and then breaks. I would like to know which of the following ways is better in means of clarity and functionality. I am aware that there are other ways to achieve the same thing. I would like to hear your thoughts and suggestions.

```
countDown = 3
while (countDown >= 0):
    print(countDown)
    countDown = countDown - 1
    if countDown == 0:
        print("Action!")
        break
```

or

```
countDown = 3
while (countDown >= 0):
    if countDown != 0:
        print(countDown)
        countDown = countDown - 1
    else:
        print("Action!")
        break
```

Comment: Are you saying it has to be a while loop?

Answer (score 20):

Why does it has to be a `while`?

Maybe it is preference but `for` loops look cleaner.

Reversing can be done by using `reversed` function which reverses a iteration

```
countdown = 3
for count in reversed(range(1, countdown+1)):
    print(count)
print('action!')
```

Or you could use the `step` parameter in `range(start, end, step)` and rewrite the for loop to

```
for count in range(countdown, 0, -1):
```

Comment: Very good point, however `list(range(1, 3, -1)) == []`. `reversed(range(1, countdown + 1))` may be easier to understand, and reason with.

Comment: IMO, `range(countdown, 0, -1)` looks cleaner and more idiomatic than `reversed(range(1, countdown+1))`. Opinions may vary, of course.

Answer (score 19):

You can get rid of some instructions by writing this instead:

```
count_down = 3
while (count_down):
   print(count_down)
   count_down -=  1
print('Action!')
```

Note that I have replaced `countDown` by `count_down` to comply with [PEP8' naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

**Code explanation:**

`count_down -= 1` is equivalent to `count_down = count_down - 1`. You can read more on [Python basic operators.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm)

You do not need to check within the while loop if `count_down` reached the 0 value because it is already done when you coded `while (countDown>=0)`. I mean you are duplicating the checking. In order to keep [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), I just decrement the value of `count_down` by 1 and the `break` instruction is done by default as I am testing `while(count_down)` meaning if `count_down != 0` in **this** context (because it also means while `count_down` is not `False` or `None`).

Comment: Why the parentheses in `while (count_down):`? And while it's somewhat a matter of taste, I'd argue that `while count_down > 0:` would express the implied intent better in this case. (In particular, it ensures that the loop will still terminate even if someone changes the initial value of `count_down` to, say, 3.5 or -1.)

Answer (score 3):

I think your first example is better in terms of clarity, although you could replace `while (countDown >= 0):` with `while (countDown > 0):`, allowing you to remove your break statement.

Ex:

```
countDown = 3
while (countDown > 0):
    print(countDown)
    countDown = countDown - 1
    if countDown == 0:
        print("Action!")
```

Answer (score 2):

**Why not try recursion? Clean and simple.**

```
num = 10

def countdown(num):
    if num == 0:
        print("Action!")
        return
    print(num)
    countdown(num-1)
countdown(num)
```

Comment: Because recursion is limited in Python and `countdown(2000)` won't reach completion? If it's simpler to use idiomatic constructs, I see no reason to bring recursion in.

Answer (score -1):

count_down = 5

while count_down > 0:

print(count_down - 1)

count_down -= 1

if count_down == 0:

print ("Action!")

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Your question currently has a very, very low quality, if it can be seen as answer at all. Please fix your code formatting and explain your reasoning on why you think the presented approach is better than the original code.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Going along with what AlexV said, it appears that you have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and why it is better than the original) so that the author and other readers can learn from your thought process. Please read [Why are alternative solutions not welcome?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8404/120114) - [From Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/116792)